# Android layout reuse

Tags: android, xml

I have an Android application that needs to use certain linear layout in several activities. For that reason, i have extracted needed linearlayout into separate xml file but now i don't know how to add that layout to other layouts.
Simply, my idea is this:

```
<xml layout id: "SomeSharedControls" />

<xml layout id:"mainWindow">
add @id SomeSharedControls
...
other xml controls in current window
...
</xml>

<xml layout id: "anotherWindow">
add @id SomeSharedControls
...
other xml controls in current window
...
</xml>
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<include>`. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/shared_view"
    layout="@layout/shared_view"/>
```

Where shared_view.xml is the file with your re-usable code.

Answer (score 0):

If your application targets Android 4+, you should use fragments. Fragments are great for UI reuse and do exactly what you want. Fragment is a self-contained piece of code with its own lifecycle (just like an Activity), which you can use from your activity almost just like any other View. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question: "...but now i don't know how to add that layout to other layouts...How to achieve that?". And you can use Fragments pre-Honeycomb using the support library.

Comment: This might not answer the question itself, but suggests an alternative and way better approach. How is that a bad thing? Imagine if all stack answers will only directly answer the OP question.

Comment: I don't like fragments... I like the things "old way" :)

Comment: Well, this is very unfortunately, since fragments can be used for modular code. This is important not only when designing for bigger screens (tablets). For example, if you had some activity showing details about something and you had it is a fragment, you can easily migrate from showing this in a separate screen to showing inline in an expandable list or maybe a ViewPager. Or maybe you will decide to go for a side navigation panel? If you use fragments from the start, transitions are simpler. Many modern applications have only 1 activity :-) I would definitely suggest to give them a shot